# jquery how to change only one parent on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, parent

I would like to change only one parent when I hover over `<p>` tags. The code is:

```
$('.hover').each(function () {
    $(this).parent().hover(function () {
            $('p').parent(this).css('font-size','30px');
        }, function () {
            $('p').parent(this).css('font-size','10px');
    });
});
```

and the HTML is:

```
   <ul>
        <li>1 <p class='hover'>xxxx</p></li>
        <li>2 <p class='hover'>yyyy</p></li>
    </ul>
```

When I hover over "xxxx", I want "1" and "xxxx" to change but "2" and "yyyy" do nothing, and when I hover over "yyyy", I want "2" and "yyyy" to change but "1" and "xxxx" do nothing.

I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: thank you to help me but it's not really what i want.
i did re-code and post it again here.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418179/jquery-how-to-change-only-one-parent-closeset-a-tag-on-hover) Thank you so much

Comment: Next time, use the "edit" button underneath your question. This allows you to modify your question. You don't have to create a new question for every edit. Right now we have an open question with multiple legit answers which is very disappointing if anyone happens to end up here with the same question.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('p.hover').parent().hover(function() {
    $(this).children('p').css('font-size','30px');
}, function () {
    $(this).children('p').css('font-size','10px');
});
```

You don't have to use an each loop to add the hovers. If you have multiple elements selected, it will apply the event on all elements.

Having that said, I slightly optimised your code.

I have added the hover on the paragraph's parent, just like you did. By using `$(this)` in the event's callback I can actually select the hovered element and apply styles on that element.

Because I want the font-size to apply on the paragraph, I select the desired child first.

---

Summing above up:

- Find the paragraphs elements (`$('p.hover')`)
- Get it's parent, the `li` element (`.parent()`)
- Apply the hover event (`.hover()`)

Once the hover event is called:

- Get current element (`$(this)`)
- Find the inner paragraph (`.children('p')`)
- Apply styles

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$('p').closest('li').css('font-size','30px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent of `<p>` in your case is `<li>`. You need:

```
$('.hover').parent().parent().hover(
    function () {
        $(this).css('font-size','30px');
    }, function () {
        $(this).css('font-size','10px');
    });
```