# jquery how to change only one parent closeset <A> tag on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, parent

I asked similar question here

[jquery how to change only one parent on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406094/jquery-how-to-change-only-one-parent-on-hover)

But it's not what I want.
so , I re-code and post it again here

I would like to change only one parent on `<a>` when I hover over `<p>` tags. The code is:

```
$('.hover').each(function () {
 $(this).parent().hover(function () {
        $('p').parent(this).css('background-color','red');
    }, function () {
        $('p').parent(this).css('background-color','black');
 });
});
```

And the HTML is:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>1</a> <p class='hover'>A</p></li>
   <li><a href='#'>2</a> <p class='hover'>B</p></li>
   <li><a href='#'>3</a> <p class='hover'>B</p></li>
   <li><a href='#'>4</a> <p class='hover'>X</p></li>
   <li><a href='#'>5</a> <p class='hover'>Y</p></li>
   <li><a href='#'>6</a> <p class='hover'>Z</p></li>
</ul>
```

What i want is when i hover "A" and **"1"** is change and other not change
and when i hover on "b" and **"2"** is change other not change also

sorry , im really new in jquery.

Comment: have you test my answer?

Comment: Yes , I did , thank you. It's work if I want to move out this 

`$(this).parent().hover(function () {...`

but i still need it could you help me to change this line?

`$('p').parent(this).css('background-color','red');`

what it should be. Thank you so much

Comment: why you want to make this way? does my answer not fulfill your need?

Comment: change `$('p').parent(this)` to `$(this).children('a')`. see my updated answer, and yes, dont forget to upvote the answer erwhichever is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need of `.each`, use [`.prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$('.hover').hover(function () {
        $(this).prev('a').css('background-color','red');
    }, function () {
        $(this).prev('a').css('background-color','yellow');
 });
```

**alternative :** you can use `.parent().children('a')` OR 
                  .`siblings('a')` instead of `.prev('a')`

​
[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/eEkDP/)

### Update

If you want to use `.each` ( as you mentioned in comment ) then do below.

```
$('.hover').each(function () {
 $(this).parent().hover(function () {
        $(this).children('a').css('background-color','red');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('a').css('background-color','yellow');
 });
});
```

[`Demo using .each`](http://jsfiddle.net/eEkDP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `closest('a')` here doesn't work because [closest navigates up the dom tree](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), not to siblings. Navigating using `.parent('li').find('a')` will find the associated 'a'

Also, as far as I can tell, you just want the hover handlers on the `<p>`, so no need for `each`.

```
$('.hover').hover(function () {
        $(this).parent('li').find('a').css('background-color','red');
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent('li').find('a').css('background-color','black');
 });
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/U4n2T/16/